# Should I be using an inner join here (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
t1:

cust_id        email
201           email1@sadpanda.com
202           email2@email.com
203           email3@sadpanda.com


t2:

cust_id     value
201         dfceaa64f8b93661903a849b09c5ac4e10abdfed21763a04d6eb9523e02d6dc1:Qs
202         c15af11e5acb2f6b7e7b12ab7eee8ce482f0cf76f76b7e65dde6b15c3a910680:Qx
203         71ae98d020b16f6f668db6bde3f9c18350a892b55736995237fa71aa5dc2b206:MU
```

I would like to select from 't1' where email is like 'sadpanda' and receive the values for those users from 't2'. Should I be using an inner join for this?

Comment: Depends if you want to get rows that don't have a corresponding in t2 or not. Why don't you read a bit about the differences in joins?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM t2
JOIN t1 USING (cust_id)
WHERE t1.email = 'email3@sadpanda.com'
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87105/2)

Answer (score 0):

you may have two ways to do it 
1. you can use simple join query . something like

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T.CUST_ID = T2.CUST_ID
WHERE T1.EMAIL LIKE '%sadpanda%'
```

1. or you can use subquery something like

   SELECT T2.*
   FROM T2
   WHERE CUST_ID IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM T1 WHERE T1.EMAIL LIKE '%sadpanda%')

I suggest first one . it will run faster then second one .